# How to create a dropdown variable with tag values in a Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, kairosdb

I am using Grafana with KairosDB as datasource.

In Grafana dashboard , I want to add a variable with ringId as name, and  Basically that dropdown will have to display all the values of tag "ringId" available in the database so that whenever new value comes under ringId tag in database it should  be pulled there.

Help me how to write a query in kairosdb to pull all the ringId's.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsvdR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `tag_values(<metric_name>, <tag_name>)`. In your case, `<metric_name>` should be a metric having `ringId` as tag.